# Folder - Sub Folder problem using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight-4.0

This might be a solved problem or a simple question. It would be great if someone could help me out on this.

I am creating a kind of folder explorer using Silverlight and WebServices. I am getting the required data for populating the folder tree view from the web service and I am using Silverlight to display it.

Here is my problem.

- 1 Folder

  - Files
  - 2 Folder

    - Files
    - 3 Folder

      - Files
      - 4 Folder ... etc.

I am able to obtain the folders till Level 2.

I tried to obtain the folders recursively. No luck using Web service. Here is my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<FolderDetails> FoldersInFolder(string UserName, string Password, string url, string FolderName)
        {
          Test(UserName, Password, url);
            ObservableCollection<FolderDetails> Folders = new ObservableCollection<FolderDetails>();
            string Temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < FoldersOnly.Count; i++)
            {
                if (FoldersOnly[i].Contains(FolderName + "/"))
                {
                    Temp = FoldersOnly[i].Substring(FoldersOnly[i].IndexOf("/") + 1);
                    if (Temp.Contains("/") == false)
                    {
                        // This is where I guess I need some help.
                        Folders.Add(new FolderDetails()
                        {
                            FolderWebUrl = url + "/" + FoldersOnly[i],
                            FolderUrl = FoldersOnly[i],
                            FolderName = Temp,                            
                            ChildFiles = FilesInFolder(UserName, Password, url, Temp),                           
                            ChildFolders = FoldersInFolder(UserName, Password, url, Temp)
                        });
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return Folders;
        }
```

Here, **FolderDetails** is a class which gives information about a folder (Folder Name, Files and Sub folders in a folder). **Username** and **Password** are used for authentication purposes (no problem with this).

**FoldersOnly** is an observablecollection of information of all folders in the directory.
**url** is the base url of the directory.

Thanks!